# To grab codeigniter database name

Tags: database, codeigniter

I want to create a database backup tool in codeigniter. So i want to grab the database name from controller. How should i do for that.
Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just use the public variable from the Database Driver object?

```
$this->db->database;
```

Answer (score 4):

it is enough to get the present(active) database in codeigniter

```
 echo $this->db->database;
```

Answer (score 4):

We can easily fetch the database details in codeigniter.

Just use below code and print this you will get all database related information:-

```
print_r($this->db);
```

You can use this like below:-

```
$this->db->database

$this->db->hostname

$this->db->username

$this->db->password
```

Answer (score 0):

1. One way is to add your config.

   $config['mydbname'] ='mydatabasename';

And call it in your controller.

```
$mydb=$this->config->item('mydbname');
$data['mydb']=$mydb;
$this->load->view('myview',$data);// it is not a good idea to show it in view.
```

2.[Use database utility class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html).

```
// use $this->dbutil->list_databases();

//Returns an array of database names:

$dbs = $this->dbutil->list_databases();

foreach ($dbs as $db)
{
    echo $db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see where you have put your code, then you can use this one:

```
var_dump($this->db->database);
```