# codeigniter set databse name in database config from session

Tags: database, codeigniter, session

Can I have get databse name from codeigniter session on database config file?
I can't use session array in config file because codeigniter config files not as controller.
Used version codeigniter 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To grab codeigniter database name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760032/to-grab-codeigniter-database-name)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

you can view all related your db information inside controller:

`var_dump($this->db);` or `print_r($this->db)`

Save it to session make new controller:

```
    private function save_database()
    {

        // save to session:

        $db_session = [
            'db_name' => $this->db->database,
            'db_hostname' => $this->db->hostname,
            'db_username' => $this->db->username,
            'db_password' => $this->db->password
        ];

        $this->session->set_userdata($db_session);


        var_dump($this->session->userdata('db_name')); // check if db_name saved into session
        //etc etc..

    }
```

call that private function wherever you want inside another controller:

`$this->save_database();`